# How to make django boolean field true using a method in django models

Tags: python, django, model

I working on an e-commerce website I have the field about new arrivals so any product which is created in the last 30 days should be listed as a new arrival.
In my models, I have a boolean field as is_new and the default value is false and I made a method to check the date whether the product is included in the new arrival list or not.
but in my method new_arrival when I return self.is_new I get an invalid syntax.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='picture/')
    is_popular = models.BooleanField()
    is_cart = models.BooleanField()
    is_new = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(aut_now_add=True)
    def new_arrival(self):
        if self.created_date >= self.created_date - self.created_date.timedelta(days=30):
            return self.is_new=True
        else:
            return self.is_new = False
```

Comment: Do you want to return a boolean from new_arrival, or do you want to assign to `self.is_new`? Doing both in one line won't work and you probably only want one.

Comment: I want to assign True to is_new if I can't assign can you explain why

Comment: Then just remove `return`.

Comment: Alex Hall thanks a lot I got it